# Select which returns multiple values doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can not understand this `select` query from t-sql - it returns multiple values:

```
select id from @tbl

id
1
2
3
4
5
```

On my logic, this should be an error:

```
select @id = id from @tbl
```

because there are multiple values selected. But, it's not an error - instead, the last inserted value is selected into `@id`. So, `@id = 5`. Why is that?

Full example here:

```
declare @tbl table
(
  id int
)

insert @tbl (id)
  values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

declare @id int
select @id = id from @tbl

select @id
```

Comment: "Why is that" - because the Microsoft engineers decided to handle it that way :)

Comment: To add to Dale's comment, it begs the question even what the "last" inserted value would be here; you never added an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I understand this - but is error, anyway. I mean, it should throw me an error.  I am trying to insert multiple values into single value.

Comment: If that is an error for your system, you'll have to add a test to handle that.

Comment: @DaleK - if that's the situation please post it as answer.

Comment: Thanks @FrenkyB but I don't think it adds anything to the SO universe. I'd just delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Why" questions are [difficult to answer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130417-00/?p=4633) because we don't know exactly what you're looking for. One answer comes from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for executing a SELECT into a local variable. That says:

> SELECT @local_variable is typically used to return a single value into
>   the variable. However, when expression is the name of a column, it can
>   return multiple values. If the SELECT statement returns more than one
>   value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned.
>
> If the SELECT statement returns no rows, the variable retains its
>   present value. If expression is a scalar subquery that returns no
>   value, the variable is set to NULL.

So basically it works this way because that's what the T-SQL engine has been designed to do. If returning multiple values should be an error in your context, you can check @@ROWCOUNT = 1. If that's false, you can throw an error.

Comment: Brilliant answer :) And guess what that documentation also says: For assigning variables, we recommend that you use SET local_variable instead of SELECT local_variable. So, if I use set instead of SELECT, it throws error on multiple rows returned.

Comment: @FrenkyB, agreed. Note that SET has other behaviour that's different to SELECT, so it's not a drop-in replacement in every case.

Answer (score 0):

```
While executing the "select id from @tbl"

The column values are physically stored inside the disk. So it fetch all the values,
but declaring variables is scope to the session so its works on the set based approach.
**SELECT** is *multi-value* attribute and **SET** is *single* value attribute.

This applicable to all relational database systems.
```